# Por que tem várias maneiras de declarar um array no C#?

Tags: c#, array, .net, sintaxe, estilo-de-codificação

Não seria mais simples ter só uma maneira de inicializar o *array*?

Algumas maneiras que eu conheço:

```
int[] array = new int[2];
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2 };
int[] array = { 1 , 2 };
int[] array = new[] { 1, 2 };
```

Tem outras formas?

Answer (score 4):

Linguagens são meios de expressão humana em primeiro ligar. Elas precisam ter formas de expressar da melhor forma para cada situação. Então é bom ter isso, desde que não seja ambíguo e não crie confusão.

E nem todas dão o mesmo resultado.

Uma outra explicação é que a linguagem começa de um jeito e vai melhorando, vai se pensando jeitos melhores e não pode abandonar o que já existia. Em alguns casos até muda-se ligeiramente a filosofia da linguagem para tomar a decisão de fazer algo novo.

Além dessas sintaxes é claro que pode declarar com `var` e não usar o tipo, mas não acho que seja a questão aqui. O terceiro não funciona com `var`.

Existem diversas maneiras usando suas próprias formas ou a biblioteca. Embora não seja exatamente a mesma coisa dos exemplos acima, poderia usar LINQ:

```
var array = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 2).ToArray();
```

Em C# 12 uma nova sintaxe surgiu para facilitar a criação:

```
var array = [ 1, 2 ];
```

Note que o `var` funciona, então não é só troca de caracteres. Assim não fica ambíguo e mantém a baixa verbosidade. E pode usar em outros contextos que o ideal é ser bem curto.

A versão traz também o operador *spread*:

```
var array2 = [ ..array, 3, 4 ]; // { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ArrayInit.cs).